# Hourly Based Column Need

Tags: oracle

```
select * 
from ( select a.wc_name as Team,
              g.name as Buyer_name,
              e.style_no,
              e.item_no,
              d.receipt_date,
              sum(c.QTY) 
       from workcenter a,
            job b,
            Job_Receipt_Details c,
            Grn_Receipt d,
            item e,
            "ORDER" f,
            buyer g 
       where C.Job_Id=b.job_id 
         and a.wc_id=b.wc_id 
         and e.order_no=f.order_no 
         and f.buyer_id=g.buyer_id 
         and c.item_no=e.item_no 
         and c.grn_no=d.grn_no 
       group by a.wc_name,
                g.name,
                e.style_no,
                e.item_no,
                receipt_date ) 
where to_date(to_char(receipt_date,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-YY')=to_date(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-YY')
```

Need hourly base separate column
Current OutPut:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Comment: MySQL knows nothing about `to_date` and `to_char` functions. Check your DBMS and re-tag the question.

Comment: What is the purpose of these `to_date(to_char(sysdate, `, and `to_date(to_char(receipt_date`? It is pointless converting a DATE into CHAR and then back again into DATE. btw, using only two digits for year `YY` may cause unexpected results, [Y2K Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to pivot your data, which - if you're on Oracle 11g or higher - you can do like so:

```
SELECT team,
       buyer_name,
       style_no,
       item_no,
       receipt_date,
       hour1,
       hour2,
       hour3,
       ...
FROM   (SELECT wc.wc_name AS team,
               buy.name AS buyer_name,
               itm.style_no,
               itm.item_no,
               trunc(gr.receipt_date) receipt_date,
               to_char(dt, 'hh24') receipt_date_hr,
               jrd.qty
        FROM   INNER JOIN job j ON wc.wc_id = j.wc_id
               INNER JOIN Job_Receipt_Details jrd ON j.job_id = jrd.job_id
               INNER JOIN Grn_Receipt gr ON jrd.grn_no = gr.grn_no
               INNER JOIN item itm ON jrd.item_no = itm.item_no
               INNER JOIN "ORDER" ord ON itm.order_no = ord.order_no
               INNER JOIN buyer buy ON ord.buyer_id = buy.buyer_id
        WHERE  receipt_date >= trunc(SYSDATE)
        AND    receipt_date < trunc(SYSDATE) + 1)
PIVOT (SUM(qty) FOR receipt_date_hr IN ('00' AS hour1, 
                                        '01' AS hour2,
                                        '02' AS hour3,
                                        ...));
```

Note that I have changed your outer query's where clause to `where receipt_date >= trunc(sysdate) and receipt_date < trunc(sysdate) + 1` to enable the use of any indexes involving the receipt_date column.

If there are no indexes on that column which might be used, then you could further simply it to `where trunc(receipt_date) = trunc(sysdate)`.